# summary() of transactions is wrong for itemMatrix object

Tags: r, transactions, summary, arules, market-basket-analysis

I am trying to do some market basket analysis using the `arules` package, but when I use the `summary()` function on an `itemMatrix` object to check which are the most frequent items, the numbers do not add up.
If I do:

```
library(arules)
x <- read.transactions("Supermarket2014-15.csv")
summary(x)
```

I get:

```
transactions as itemMatrix in sparse format with
 5001 rows (elements/itemsets/transactions) and
 997 columns (items) and a density of 0.003557162 

most frequent items:    
45      28      42      35      22 (Other) 
503     462     444     440     413   15474
```

But if I check with a `for` loop, or even in Excel, the count for the product 45 is 513 and not 503. The same for 28, which should be 499, and so on.
The odd thing is if I sum up all the totals `(15474+413+440+444+462+503)` I get the correct number for the total of transacted products.

The data has several `NA` values and products are factors.

[image: str(x)]

And here is the raw data (Day ranges from 1 to 28, Product ranges from 1 to 50):

[image: Raw Data]

Comment: actually, I'm not sure.  Is there any chance we can have a reproducible example?

Comment: ... and are there any `NA` values in your data set?

Comment: I also wonder if the products are numbers or a factor. If a factor,  do you have "45" and "45 "  with a blank?

Comment: try `str(x)` and show as the result please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is still not reproducible (and please don't post screenshots -- cut and paste text instead) -- please read [mcve] and [this set of r-specific advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)  ...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the result of your `str(x)` call then you see under `@iteminfo` and `$labels` that some items have labels like `"1;1"`, etc. This means that the items are not correctly separated after reading the file in. The default separator in `read.transactions()` is a white space, but you seem to have (some) semicolons there. Try `sep=";"` in `read.transactions()`.